# The best way to check if time is between two hours in momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to do something like 'night mode' in my app and I need to check if current time f.e 22:30 will be in the range of field 'startNight' and 'endNight'.

I'm trying to compare the total minutes for these fields like below:

```
function mode (nightStart, nightEnd) { //params disabled for example
      const now = moment('01:00', 'HH:mm');
      const nightStart = moment('22:00', 'HH:mm');
      const nightEnd = moment('06:00', 'HH:mm');

      return now.isBetween(nightStart, nightEnd);
}
```

It works for example range '01:00' - '03:00' and check between these hours, but I want to figure out if I set the nightStart for '22:00' and nightEnd to '06:00', because it says me now that 01:00 is not between 22:00 and 06:00.

I guess I must handle times before and after midnight, but maybe there is another easier way to do this.

Many thanks for help.

Comment: You wanna check 7.30 PM is between 7PM and 8PM right?

Comment: I wanna check if in 24h time format 01:00 is between 22:00 and 06:00. Currently works in comparing PM hours only, and also for AM hours only, but if `nightStart` is set as 22:00 and `nightEnd` is set as 06:00, hours after 22:00 and before 06:00  returning false.

Comment: Is there a restriction where you would not want to initialize moment object with **date** as indicated by @JunsukPark below? If not i think his answer is what you are looking for

Comment: @Samleo You're right. I thought that there will be an easy way to compare the only a range of HH:mm but it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should initialize moment object with the date 
For example,

```
const now = moment()
const nightStart = moment("2019-02-22 01:00:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
const nightEnd = moment("2019-02-22 13:00:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")

now.isBetween(nightStart, nightEnd) // returns true
```